# Comando javascript não funciona dentro do Buttom

Tags: php, javascript, div

Bom dia!
Estou com um problema e não estou conseguindo resolver a questão.
Preciso que um buttom apareça ou não de acordo com a condição PHP.
Fazer o buttom aparecer estou conseguindo, a questão é que dentro dele tem uma chamada javascript que não funciona dentro do PHP. Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Seguem os códigos:

```
<header>
<script type="text/javascript">
function exibe(id) {
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display=="none") {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</header>

<body>
<?php  
    if (get('data_do_descredenciamento')!= ''){
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn" href="#" onclick="javascript: exibe('conteudo');">SUBSTITUTO</button>';
    }
?>
</body>
```

Está dando erro no conteúdo: `onclick="javascript: exibe('conteudo')`

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: O que é esse `conteudo`? é uma string? Tens de escapar essas aspas simples... assim: `exibe(\'conteudo\');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é por causa das aspas.
Segue algumas alternativas para resolver seu problema:

**1° Concatenar aspas.**

```
echo "<button type='button' class='btn' onclick="."exibe('conteudo');".">SUBSTITUTO</button>";
```

**2º Escapar aspas simples**

```
echo '<button type="button" class="btn" href="#" onclick="javascript: exibe(\'conteudo\');">SUBSTITUTO</button>';
```

**3º Variável com o onclick**

```
$button_onclick = "onclick="."exibe('conteudo');"."";
echo "<button type='button' class='btn' href='#' $button_onclick>SUBSTITUTO</button>";
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Substitua isso:

```
onclick="javascript: exibe('conteudo');"
```

Por isso:

```
onclick="javascript: exibe(\'conteudo\');"
```